# Getting an event called after a document is loaded

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-dna

How can I create a method that will get called immediately after a document is loaded (using Excel-DNA)?
Is there any support for such functionality in Excel-DNA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an Excel-DNA add-in you have full access to both the C API and the COM object model. For this case, the COM object model provides events to track which Workbooks are open.

In an add-in library you can add a reference to the interop assembly `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, either directly or by using the `ExcelDna.Interop` NuGet package.

Then there are two requirements for safely using the COM object model from an Excel-DNA add-in:

1. Only make COM calls from the main Excel thread.
2. Get hold of the root `Application` object for the hosting Excel instance with a call to `ExcelDnaUtil.Application`.

To get notified when a Workbook is opened, you then add an event handlers for the `NewWorkbook` and `WorkbookOpen` events on the `Application` object.

Comment: Is there any way to make this work with all Excel versions since 2007?

Comment: This part of the COM object model is the same in all those versions, so your .NET code will work in all versions.

Comment: But the NuGet package is targeting Excel 2010. Will it work if I just use this package and install my addin to another version of Excel?

Comment: Yes - it will work fine. It's the same as if you wrote the code in VBA on an Excel 2010 - it will work on an Excel 2007 or Excel 2016 too, as long as you use only parts of the object model that are available on the Excel version where it runs.